# What's the issue with the way I'm binding to a dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

**Note:** You can find the project below on github now. https://github.com/ReasonSharp/MyTestRepo

I'm creating a simple list control with a scrollbar that will display a collection of objects I pass to it. When a user clicks on one item, I want it to become a selected item, and when he clicks it again, I want it to be unselected. I store the selected item in a `SelectedLocation` property. While debugging, the property is set appropriately. However, if I place this list control (`LocationListView`) onto a window and bind to `SelectedLocation` (like `SelectedLocation="{Binding MyLocation}"`) in a control, the binding won't work, and if I try to use this `MyLocation` in another binding in the same window (i.e. `<TextBox Text="{Binding MyLocation.ID}"/>`, where `ID` is a dependency property), that binding won't show anything changing as I select different items in the list.

Minimal example is a bit large, please bear with me:

**List control**

*XAML*

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyListView.LocationListView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyListView"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
 <Grid x:Name="locationListView">
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

*Code behind*

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyListView {
 public partial class LocationListView : UserControl {
  #region Dependency Properties
  public IEnumerable Locations {
   get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(LocationsProperty); }
   set { SetValue(LocationsProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationsProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("Locations", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(LocationListView), new PropertyMetadata(null, LocationsChanged));

  public MyObject SelectedLocation {
   get { return (MyObject)GetValue(SelectedLocationProperty); }
   set { SetValue(SelectedLocationProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedLocationProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedLocation", typeof(MyObject), typeof(LocationListView), new PropertyMetadata(null));
  #endregion

  private static void LocationsChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
   ((LocationListView)o).RegenerateLocations();
   if (((LocationListView)o).Locations is ObservableCollection<MyObject>) {
    var l = ((LocationListView)o).Locations as ObservableCollection<MyObject>;
    l.CollectionChanged += ((LocationListView)o).L_CollectionChanged;
   }
  }

  private void L_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
   RegenerateLocations();
  }

  private Button selectedLV = null;

  public LocationListView() {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void RegenerateLocations() {
   if (Locations != null) {
    myStackPanel.Children.Clear();
    foreach (var l in Locations) {
     var b = new Button();
     b.Content = l;
     b.Click += B_Click;
     myStackPanel.Children.Add(b);
    }
   }
   selectedLV = null;
  }

  private void B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   var lv = (sender as Button)?.Content as MyObject;
   if (selectedLV != null) {
    lv.IsSelected = false;
    if ((selectedLV.Content as MyObject) == SelectedLocation) {
     SelectedLocation = null;
     selectedLV = null;
    }
   }
   if (lv != null) {
    SelectedLocation = lv;
    selectedLV = sender as Button;
    lv.IsSelected = true;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Note the absence of `this.DataContext = this;` line. If I use it, I get the following binding expression path errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SillyStuff' property not found on 'object' ''LocationListView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=SillyStuff; DataItem='LocationListView' (Name=''); target element is 'LocationListView' (Name=''); target property is 'Locations' (type 'IEnumerable')
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'MySelectedLocation' property not found on 'object' ''LocationListView' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MySelectedLocation; DataItem='LocationListView' (Name=''); target element is 'LocationListView' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedLocation' (type 'MyObject')
```

Using `(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` won't produce these errors, but it won't work either.

**Main window**

*XAML*

```
<Window x:Class="MyListView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyListView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Grid>
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <local:LocationListView Locations="{Binding SillyStuff}" SelectedLocation="{Binding MySelectedLocation}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
   <TextBox Text="{Binding MySelectedLocation.ID}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
  </DockPanel>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

*Code behind*

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace MyListView {
 public partial class MainWindow : Window {
  private MainViewModel vm;

  public MainWindow() {
   InitializeComponent();
  }

  [Dependency] // Unity
  internal MainViewModel VM {
   set {
    this.vm = value;
    this.DataContext = vm;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

*MainViewModel*

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyListView {
 class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
   if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(sender, e);
  }

  private MyObject mySelectedLocation;
  public MyObject MySelectedLocation {
   get { return mySelectedLocation; }
   set {
    mySelectedLocation = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedLocation"));
   }
  }

  public ObservableCollection<MyObject> SillyStuff {
   get; set;
  }

  public MainViewModel() {
   var cvm1 = new MyObject();
   cvm1.ID = 12345;

   var cvm2 = new MyObject();
   cvm2.ID = 54321;

   var cvm3 = new MyObject();
   cvm3.ID = 15243;

   SillyStuff = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
   SillyStuff.Add(cvm1);
   SillyStuff.Add(cvm2);
   SillyStuff.Add(cvm3);
  }
 }
}
```

**MyObject**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyListView {
 public class MyObject : DependencyObject {
  public int ID {
   get { return (int)GetValue(IDProperty); }
   set { SetValue(IDProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IDProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ID", typeof(int), typeof(MyObject), new PropertyMetadata(0));

  public bool IsSelected {
   get; set;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
   return ID.ToString();
  }
 }
}
```

**App.xaml** -- just to save anyone the typing

*XAML*

```
<Application x:Class="MyListView.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyListView">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

*Code behind*

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;

namespace MyListView {
 public partial class App : Application {
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) {
   base.OnStartup(e);

   UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
   var mainView = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
   container.Dispose();
   mainView.Show();
  }
 }
}
```

The objective here is to have the value in the `TextBox` on `MainWindow` change to the selected item's ID whenever the selected item changes. I could probably do it by creating a `SelectedItemChanged` event on my `LocationListView`, and then setting the property manually in a handler, but that seems like a hack. If you place a `<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SillyStuff}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedLocation}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>` instead of my list control, this works like a charm, so I should be able to make my control work that way too.

**Edit:** Changed `MainViewModel` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` as per Pieter's instructions.

Comment: View models should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, they don't need to be `DependencyObject`s and don't need to contain `DependencyProperty`s. UI controls already have those and that's enough for the binding system to work with. View models just need to notify the UI when their properties change.

Comment: OK, looks like I'm using this practice since I viewed the first tutorial that demonstrated MVVM (among other patterns). I've changed that now, but this didn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Bart The sample is on GitHub now. https://github.com/ReasonSharp/MyTestRepo

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're creating a custom control instead of using a `ListView` or `ItemsControl` with a custom `ItemTemplate`? It shouldn't be too hard to customize them to get the selection behavior you're looking for.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet You're right, I might be better off asking how to put a custom control in place of a `ListViewItem` or some such thing (I'm displaying buttons with custom controls instead of text in production), but I thought about this before I began making my own control and decided I could add functionality to my own control faster than I could find out how to make something work in one of the existing list controls. Since I asked this question, however, might I have an answer to that instead, if it exists (and everything tells me it should)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main issues**

When you select an item in your custom control, `B_Click` assigns it to the `SelectedLocation` property, which calls `SetValue` internally. However, this overwrites the binding on `SelectedLocation` - in other words, after that call `SelectedLocation` is no longer bound to anything. Use [`SetCurrentValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to preserve the binding.

However, bindings won't update their source by default. You'll have to set their `Mode` to `TwoWay`. You can do that in XAML: `SelectedLocation="{Binding MySelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}"`, or mark the dependency property to use `TwoWay` binding by default: `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, LocationsChanged)`.

Finally, make sure that your binding paths are correct. Your text box binds to `SelectedLocation`, while the property is named `MySelectedLocation`. These kind of issues are usually logged in the debug output, in this case you should get a message like this:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedLocation' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=8757408)'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedLocation.ID; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=8757408); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

**Other issues**

I've found a few other issues as well: you're not unregistering `L_CollectionChanged` when another collection is set, and if the collection is removed, you're not clearing the visible items. The code in `B_Click` is also troublesome: you're also accessing `lv` before making sure it's not null, and if the user clicks on an unselected button you're setting `SelectedLocation` to null before setting it to the newly selected item. Also, when regenerating items, `selectedLV` (what's 'lv'?) is set to null, but `SelectedLocation` is left intact...

Also a little tip: your `OnPropertyChanged` method only needs a single argument: `string propertyName`. Make it optional and mark it with a `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, so all that a property setter needs to do is call it without arguments. The compiler will insert the calling property name for you.

**Alternatives**

Personally, I'd just use a `ListView` with a custom `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyLocations}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedLocation}" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This probably requires a few more modifications to make it look nice, but that's the gist of it. Alternately, you could create an attached behavior that takes care of your desired selection behavior.

Comment: `SetCurrentValue` didn't work, that is, the behavior is the same as before. As for unregistering, I've set this aside because the solution to that is non-trivial. I'd need a private variable to store the old collection, because by the time `LocationsChanged` is invoked, I'd already lost the reference to it. Now you mention that, I noticed I also didn't unregister `B_Click`. I'm thinking if I can't solve the issue with `SelectedLocation` then there's no point fixing the leak as I won't be using the control at all.

Comment: Ooh, I forgot there's a `NewValue` and `OldValue` in `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`. My bad. It's trivial then. Still, that doesn't help my main issue.

Comment: I've had some time to test your code and found the remaining problems. I also found a few more minor issues. As for unregistering an event listener, just use a private variable. It's good practice to tie those loose ends up before they turn into bugs that take hours to chase down. ;)

Comment: This updated answer worked after creating a two-way binding in `SelectedLocationProperty` registration line. It doesn't matter whether I'm using `SetValue` or `SetCurrentValue`. Sorry about the incorrect binding path, that must have become messed up in the many changes I made to the example. `lv` is short for `LocationViewer`, a custom control which, in production, is displayed in the `StackPanel` for each item I want to show in `LocationListView`. Also, in `B_Click` I'm only setting `SelectedLocation` to null if it's a currently selected location. That's the desired behavior.

Comment: Your other tips are very useful and thanks for taking the time to address all these issues.

Comment: No problem. :) `SetCurrentValue` does matter - with `SetValue` you'll destroy the binding, so `MySelectedLocation` in the main window view model won't get updated anymore (you can call `GetBindingExpression(SelectedLocationProperty)` to verify this). And check `B_Click` carefully: it really does set `CurrentLocation` to null before setting it to the newly selected object. It works, but it's sloppy.

Comment: Ah, OK. I obviously need to invest more time to make examples I post here better coded. Most of this code is just a simplified version of my production code and my main objective was to create the simplest example that demonstrates what I'm stuck with, not to write good code. In the process of simplification I've made a number of oversights such as this and should probably be more careful in the future. Ultimately it would save everyone the time. Again thanks for your help and rest assured my production code will be written to the highest standards. :)

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, that's a lot of code.

Let me begin by highlighting a common mistake, which is setting the control's `DataContext` to itself. This should be avoided as it tends to screw up absolutely everything.

So. Avoid doing this:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

It is not the responsibility of the `UserControl` itself to set it's own `DataContext`, it should be the responsibility of the parent control (such as a `Window` to set it. Like this:

```
<Window ...>
    <local:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}" ... />
```

If your `UserControl` was to set its own `DataContext`, then it will override what the `Window` sets its `DataContext` to be. Which will result in the screwing up of absolutely everything.

To bind to a **Dependency Property** of a `UserControl`, simply give your control an `x:Name` and use an `ElementName` binding, like this:

```
<UserControl ...
    x:Name="usr">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDependencyProperty, ElementName=usr}" ... />
```

What's important to note here is that the `DataContext` isn't being set **at all**, so your parent `Window` is free to set the control's `DataContext` to whatever it needs to be.

Adding to this, your `UserControl` can now bind to it's `DataContext` using a straightforward `Path` binding.

```
<UserControl ...
    x:Name="usr">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeDataContextProperty}" ... />
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got it to work by binding my `TextBox.Text` property to the control's `SelectedLocations.ID` property using `ElementName=usr`. That still doesn't do anything to my property in my `MainViewModel` and I need it to be changed in working conditions. Like I said in my post, I didn't use `this.DataContext = this;` at all, so per what you say, everything should be working smoothly, yet it isn't. Also, why would my main window need to set the data context to the control? If I place a `ListView` instead of my control, I don't need to set its `DataContext`, yet this example works perfectly.